# How to constrain hline of double line table border to inner border?

Tags: tables, rules, hhline

I want to keep the horizontal line of this table to the inner border of a double line table. Is this possible? I'd like to prevent the line from extending to the outer border as highlighted in the image below:

[image]

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\refstepcounter{table}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{||l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l||} 
\hhline{|t:==========:t|}
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{10}{||l||}{} \\
\hhline{|b:==========:b|}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `\hhline` for that horizontal line as well:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|| *{10}{l |} |} 
    \hhline{|t:*{10}{=}:t|}
     &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
    \hhline{|| *{10}{-} ||}
    \multicolumn{10}{||l||}{}   \\
    \hhline{|b:*{10}{=}:b|}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For information, here is a way to construct that table but putting a standard environment `{tabular}` in `\fbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}

\fbox{%
\begin{tabular}{|*{10}{c|}}
\hline
& & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
\multicolumn{10}{|c|}{} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]